# got TRUE AND FALSE when i using formula in VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel

ok i noob when using vba excel and trying using formula trough vba excel when i trying to use it :

```
Sheet1.Range("UA14") = ActiveCell.Formula = "=SUMIFS('BERKAS MASUK'!I20:I1698, 'BERKAS MASUK'!M20:M1698, " >= " & RANGKUMAN!TY9,'BERKAS MASUK'!M20:M1698, " <= " & RANGKUMAN!TZ9)"
```

i got FALSE in my UA14 and when i using R1C1

```
Sheet1.Range("UA14").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIFS('BERKAS MASUK'!R[7]C[-536]:R[1685]C[-536], 'BERKAS MASUK'!R[7]C[-532]:R[1685]C[-532], " >= " & RANGKUMAN!R[-4]C,'BERKAS MASUK'!R[7]C[-532]:"
```

I got TRUE in my UA14 can someone help me solve this >.< i need sumifs result not true or false in my UA14

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. When you use a string in VBA and there are double quotes inside the string, you need to type two double quote signs.
2. your first formula should use  `Sheet1.Range("UA14").Formula = "=Sumifs.....`

So if you want this formula in a cell

```
=SUMIFS('Sheet one'!$B:$B,'Sheet one'!$C:$C, ">=" & C1)
```

... you need to use this VBA (note the double "" around the `>=`):

```
Range("a1").Formula = "=Sumifs('Sheet One'!$B:$B,'Sheet One'!$C:$C, "">="" & C1)"
```

[image]

Comment: THANKS teylyn it's work >.< so its need double " thanks

Comment: If my post solved your problem please mark it as the answer as described in the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

Excel is doing what you are telling it to - evaluating whether the string

```
"=SUMIFS('BERKAS MASUK'!R[7]C[-536]:R[1685]C[-536], 'BERKAS MASUK'!R[7]C[-532]:R[1685]C[-532], "
```

is **GREATER THAN OR EQUAL TO**

```
" & RANGKUMAN!R[-4]C,'BERKAS MASUK'!R[7]C[-532]:"
```

Review your code again, and decide what formula you actually want to populate into your cell.